# Can I add hidden form fields at submit time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an additional hidden form field when submitting a form but can't see it in the POST'ed form data after submission.

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){        
var hiddenInput = $('<input data-role="none"/>').attr({type:'hidden',name:'myname',value: 'somevalue'});
 $('#myform').appendTo(hiddenInput);
});
```

The form submits but does not include the hidden field.

Comment: You want to add the form to the field? Because your code does that $('#myform').appendTo(hiddenInput); should be $('#myform').append(hiddenInput); or the over way round: $(hiddenInput).appendTo('#myform');?

Comment: Why would you want to generate the hidden form field dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.append()` the way you have written it.

You're trying to append the form to the input with that `.appendTo()` syntax .

Answer (score 1):

You have appended `#myform` to `hiddenInput` but not vice versa.

Instead try the following for your `submit` event:

```
$('<input data-role="none" />').attr({
    type: "hidden",
    name: "myname",
    value: "somevalue"
}).appendTo(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myform').on("submit",function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#myform').append('<input type="hidden" name="myname" value="somevalue" data-role="none"/>');

    $(this).submit();
});
```